# Android Wear emulator

Tags: android, wear-os

I am just starting with android wearable, I tried connecting the handheld device with the emulator it worked well too.  Is there any method available to connect an android emulator with a wearable emulator.

Comment: have u install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app

Comment: yes I did, installed

Comment: have u connect your phone with wear emulator

Comment: please tried this one http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/49586/how-do-i-connect-an-android-wear-emulator-to-a-real-phone/